# Rename all files to lowercase, replace spaces

Tags: windows, cmd, rename

In a Windows command prompt, how can I rename all the files to lower case and remove all spaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a batch file

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ( ' dir /b /a-d *.* ') do (
set name="%%i"
set newname=!name: =!
rename "%%i" !newname!
)
```

NOTE: Run under a test directory and see if you have the expected result. I have not tested it.

EDIT: Forgot to say this will only remove the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I used this batch file to rename all folders and subfolders to lowercase names:

```
@ECHO OFF
CALL:GETDIRS

:GETDIRS
FOR /F "delims=" %%s IN ('DIR /B /L /AD') DO (
    RENAME "%%s" "%%s"
    CD "%%s"
    CALL:GETDIRS
    CD ..
)
GOTO:EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

To make the trick of "lowercase" and "remove spaces" ...

In the given solution, in the 'dir' statement, use also "/l"

> The /L statement in dir forces to lowercase the filenames in the
>   result.

As "Windows-RENAME" command, if you use the "same" filename, it will note convert from uppercase to lowercase.

```
ren XPTO.TXT xpto.txt
```

The result will always be : XPTO.TXT

To 'bypass' this, we use the ephemeral technique:
move old to temp, then -> move temp to new

Then the solution would be:

```
@echo off
if exist temporaryfilenametorename del temporaryfilenametorename /f/q
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir *.csv /l /b /a-d') do (
set name="%%i"
set newname=!name: =!
rename "%%i" temporaryfilenametorename
rename temporaryfilenametorename !newname!
)
```