# Batch script to create a folder per image

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with 100 images. All images are named this way:

```
FOLDER
 - MY COOL IMAGE.JPG
 - MY COOL IMAGE 2.JPG
 - MY COOL IMAGE 3.JPG
 ...
```

I would need to create a folder per image witch will have the same name as correspondant image.

```
FOLDERS
 -my-cool-image
   - MY COOL IMAGE.JPG
 -my-cool-image-2
   - MY COOL IMAGE 2.JPG
 -my-cool-image-3
   - MY COOL IMAGE 3.JPG
 ...
```

I'm on windows, and look for a script to automate this.

If someone can help with some links and/or sample code, I would appreciate a lot.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use the `FOR` command with it's modifiers options to get the base name of the file name without the extension.  Then use the `MD` command from the results of the `FOR` command to make the directory.  This could literally be one line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution would be this one line of code.

```
FOR %%G IN (*.jpg) DO MD "%%~nG"
```

The `~n` modifier tells it to give you the base file name without the extension.

To move the file to the new directory just use the move command.

```
FOR %%G IN (*.jpg) DO (
    MD "%%~nG"
    move "%%~G" "%%~nG\"
)
```

Here is your final code with the lower case and hyphens.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

For %%G IN (*.jpg) DO (
    set "str=%%~nG"
    set "str=-!str: =-!"
    call :toLower str
    MD "!str!"
    move "%%~G" "!str!\"
)

GOTO :EOF
:toLower str -- converts uppercase character to lowercase
::           -- str [in,out] - valref of string variable to be converted
:$created 20060101 :$changed 20080219 :$categories StringManipulation
:$source https://www.dostips.com
if not defined %~1 EXIT /b
for %%a in ("A=a" "B=b" "C=c" "D=d" "E=e" "F=f" "G=g" "H=h" "I=i"
            "J=j" "K=k" "L=l" "M=m" "N=n" "O=o" "P=p" "Q=q" "R=r"
            "S=s" "T=t" "U=u" "V=v" "W=w" "X=x" "Y=y" "Z=z" "Ä=ä"
            "Ö=ö" "Ü=ü") do (
    call set "%~1=%%%~1:%%~a%%"
)
EXIT /b
```

I totally forgot about the `/L` option with the `DIR` command.  That shortens up the code considerably.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

For /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /A-D /B /L *.jpg') DO (
    set "str=%%~nG"
    set "str=-!str: =-!"
    MD "!str!"
    move "%%~G" "!str!\"
)
```

I am going to add some more code examples because it is so easy to add on the additional code into this one to another question you asked.

To create an empty text file in the newly created directory would just be one line of extra code.  You use the redirection operator which is a greater than symbol to send the output to the file. We are going to use the type command with the NUL device to create an empty file. You can name the file whatever you want.

```
type nul>"!str!\file.txt"
```

If you want to put something inside the file then use the `ECHO` command.

```
echo I want this in the text file>"!str!\file.txt"
```

Use either of those examples after the `MOVE` command.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, as perfect newbie with batch files, I've an error pasting this code: It says brackets are missing before/after keyword "FOR". I'm sur I miss some basics :(

Comment: @diplomatico, this is a batch file.  Not a Powershell script.  Save that one line of code into a file name **whatever.bat** and run it from a cmd prompt or run it by double clicking it with your mouse.  Don't try it run it from a powershell prompt.

Comment: Shame on me!! thank you @Squachman. Of course now it works better :)
I'll now try to find some solution to place image in respective folder, rename folder and image to lowercase and separate words in title with a -.

Comment: @diplomatico, to move the file just use the move command. Casing in the Windows world is cosmetic.  A file name with the same characters regardless of the case is the same name.

Comment: yes, I agree with you. In this case, I need to case folder titles because they are used as page title in a CMS. That's why it is important to have them in lower case and spaces being replaced by -. 
The only (working) script I found to make titles folder to lowercase is this one: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914210/9974853
Thank you for the move command.

Comment: @Squachman: A big big thanks. You will make me love batch files! (Sorry for poor comment, I don't have enough reputations to go to chat)

Comment: @diplomatico, I answered your other question here as well.  I just gave you some basic code examples on how to create a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Again thank you @Squachman.

Now my code looks like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

For /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /A-D /B /L *.jpg') DO (
set "str=%%~nG"
set "str= !str: =-!"
call :toLower str
MD "!str!"
move "%%~G" "!str!\"
type nul>"!str!\file.txt"
echo title: %%~nG>"!str!\file.txt"
)

GOTO :EOF
:toLower str -- converts uppercase character to lowercase
::           -- str [in,out] - valref of string variable to be converted
:$created 20060101 :$changed 20080219 :$categories StringManipulation
:$source https://www.dostips.com
if not defined %~1 EXIT /b
for %%a in ("A=a" "B=b" "C=c" "D=d" "E=e" "F=f" "G=g" "H=h" "I=i"
        "J=j" "K=k" "L=l" "M=m" "N=n" "O=o" "P=p" "Q=q" "R=r"
        "S=s" "T=t" "U=u" "V=v" "W=w" "X=x" "Y=y" "Z=z" "Ä=ä"
        "Ö=ö" "Ü=ü") do (
call set "%~1=%%%~1:%%~a%%"
)
EXIT /b
```

Now I would need to lowercase the added text in .txt file

I go on my test, and happy to learn a lot ;-)

Comment: You don't need to use the lowercase function in your code. That is why I removed it from the other code example because the /L option is making the output in lowercase. Everything you output to the text file is in lowercase.

Comment: Unfortunatly not. Text is not output to lowercase nor folder titles, if I don't use lower case fonction :(
If I use the function, only folders titles are outputed to lowercase.

Comment: Both my full code examples put the file name to lowercase. I tested them extensively before I put them in my answer. I see you changed a few things that might cause failures. That will have to wait until tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Squachman ;)

I have created a script for moving all the ebooks (pdf, epub, mobi, azw3) to subfolders and create the folder.jpg inside the folder. ;)

Tested on Windows 10 needs Calibre installed for extract the covers.

- NAME=2folders.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo.
echo MOVING .PDF
echo.
For /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /A-D /B /L *.pdf') DO (
    set "str=%%~nG"
    set "str=!str: =_!"
    MD "!str!"
    ebook-meta "%%~G" --get-cover="!str!\folder.jpg"
    move "%%~G" "!str!\"
)
echo.
echo MOVING .EPUB
echo.
For /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /A-D /B /L *.epub') DO (
    set "str=%%~nG"
    set "str=!str: =_!"
    MD "!str!"
    ebook-meta "%%~G" --get-cover="!str!\folder.jpg"
    move "%%~G" "!str!\"
)
echo.
echo MOVING .MOBI
echo.
For /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /A-D /B /L *.mobi') DO (
    set "str=%%~nG"
    set "str=!str: =_!"
    MD "!str!"
    ebook-meta "%%~G" --get-cover="!str!\folder.jpg"    
    move "%%~G" "!str!\"
)
echo.
echo MOVING .azw3
echo.
For /f "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /A-D /B /L *.azw3') DO (
    set "str=%%~nG"
    set "str=!str: =_!"
    MD "!str!"
    ebook-meta "%%~G" --get-cover="!str!\folder.jpg"    
    move "%%~G" "!str!\"
)
```